# I am unable to run python file because this line is returning SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

When I try to run main() it returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at `print(f"Results from Sampling (n = {SAMPLES})")`
in Python 3.7

```
SAMPLES = 1000

def main():

    print(f"Results from Sampling (n = {SAMPLES})")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Comment: What line?  What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: Your code worked fine when I copy/pasted your code into my Python 3.7.1 environment.  On the other hand, when I originally loaded the page, `print(...)` and `main()` were not indented, and an empty function is an error.  But that's an "IntentationError", not a "SyntaxError".  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted your code as it is then there are 2 issues here.
1st is indentation second is syntax.

1. You can read about python indentation here: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html
2. The `__name` should be changed to `__name__`

Code below should work

```
SAMPLES = 1000

def main():
    print(f"Results from Sampling (n = {SAMPLES})")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```